# which class do I need to style?

Tags: html, css, hover

here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4sesoafo/10/

I have this menu I am trying to style. Everything is done except that I need the "ABOUT" to become blue as well when the menu is hovered. For the moment, when you hover the menu but then hover its childs, "ABOUT" stays white and is not visible.

Any css guru that can help me ?

Thank you !

Guillaume

EDIT:

**Normal state**: 
[image]
**What I have now**:
[image]
**What I want**:
[image]
**What I don't want**:
[image]

ps: here is JSFiddle's html code because I need to put it here.

```
<div class="test">

<nav class="primary-nav" id="nav-wrap">
                    <div class="sf-menu">
          <ul>
            <li class="page_item page-item-8 page_item_has_children"><a href="">About</a>
              <ul class="children">
                <li class="page_item page-item-16"><a href="">History / Mission / Vision</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-1372"><a href="">Meet The Team</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-1011"><a href="">Our Expertise</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-20"><a href="">Our Clients</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-21"><a href="">Our Partners</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-22"><a href="">Careers</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-507"><a href="">Case Studies</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          </div>    
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.sf-menu ul:hover .page_item_has_children > a{
  color: blue;
}
```

This will apply the color blue to the header when the UL has been hovered over.

Edit. Lets say you want the "About" menu to have a blue header on hover and a "Products" menu to have a red header on hover you would do the following.

Add an ID to each item you want to change. In your case it would be the A tag for the menu header (I've added a "Products header also for this example)

First add an id to the UL for the menu itself

```
<ul id="about-menu">

<ul id="products-menu">
```

Then

```
<li class="page_item page-item-8 page_item_has_children"><a href="" id="about-header">About</a>

<li class="page_item page-item-9 page_item_has_children"><a href="" id="products-header">Products</a>
```

Now the CSS I mentioned earlier will apply the blue to both.

In order to treat each header differently you need to tell the CSS to treat them differently. In my initial CSS there was nothing to differentiate between similar links but now we have given each one an ID. Because of this we can do the following.

```
.sf-menu ul#about-menu:hover .page_item_has_children > a#about-header{
  color: blue;
}
.sf-menu ul#products-menu:hover .page_item_has_children > a#products-header{
  color: red;
}
```

If you really want to you could also now get rid of some of the css selectors. I wouldn't, but that's up to you - it will not make a difference at the end of the day.

```
ul#about-menu:hover a#about-header{
  color: blue;
}
ul#products-menu:hover a#products-header{
  color: red;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, your solution works if I only have 1 menu. But if I have others <li> like "About" it change them as well. Any idea ?

Comment: This should work for all menus using the same structure. I'll edit my answer to show you how to do what I think your mean

Comment: While I try to do sometyhing with your last answer, I edited my original question to show you exactly what I want. Your first solution is showed in the last picture. I don't think I can't add IDs because the coide is generated by something. Maybe I can use the class "page-item-x" ?

Comment: Have you tried the first piece of CSS I gave you? That should work. You could use the class "page-item-x which would make your css look like this `.sf-menu ul:hover .page_item-x > a{
  color: blue;
}`  Edit: now I see the problem. Use the css above and it should be all good to go

Comment: tried adding this css to everything:
.sf-menu ul:hover .page-item-8 > a{ color: #0c0035; }
.sf-menu ul:hover .page-item-10 > a{ color: #0c0035; }
.sf-menu ul:hover .page-item-12 > a{ color: #0c0035; }
.sf-menu ul:hover .page-item-14 > a{ color: #0c0035; }
.sf-menu ul:hover .page-item-965 > a{ color: #0c0035; }

But then everything is becoming blue again when I hover one of them

Comment: Try adding a unique ID to the UL before the About link. `<ul id="about-menu">` then change css to `.sf-menu ul#about-menu:hover > a`

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry it took so long to fully understand your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add id to `a` tag and place this code to `css`:

```
#about:hover{
  color: blue !important;
}
```

[LINK to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4sesoafo/13/)